# MVP в Android приложении

Tags: android, mvp

Писал приложение под Android, но со временем, когда понадобилось расширять проект, оказалось много подводных камней, сопровождение проекта  и его тестирование стало неудобным, код стал слишком замороченным. На просторах интернета нашел кучу примеров MVP патерна. Но столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не могу корректно разделить View и Presenter. Вот например в Activity был код:

В данном куске кода есть как логика (создание фрагментов, добавление в стек и т.д.), так и работа с компонентами (закрытие NavigationDrawer, смена заголовка и.т.д).

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    try {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new OneFragment();
                break;
            //и т.д.
        } 
        clearBackStack(); //очищаем содержимое стека фрагментов
        if (fragment != null) {
                mLvNavigationDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mLvNavigationDrawer.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]); //устанавливаем заголовок navMenuTitles - массив заголовков пунктов меню

                SystemUtils.selectFragmentAddStack(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment); //добавляем новый фрагмент в стек фрагментов
            }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvNavigationDrawer); //закрываем NavigationDrawer
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //сообщаем об ошибке
    }
}
```

Поэтому возникает следующий вопрос: Как правильно отделить логику от работы с компонентами в вышеприведенном коде (в случае MVP)? Как вы организовываете архитектуру своих проектов, чтобы в дальнейшем удобно расширять ее и сопровождать?

Comment: На ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа.

Comment: В андроид, в основном, используется паттерн MVC. Классический пример - ListView: model - адаптер , view - сам виджет, controler - активити (связывание списка и адаптера). С недавних пор доступен и MVVM так популярный в windows C# разработке - с появлением официальной библиотеки Data Binding Library. Вообще по архитектурным паттернам в андроид написано достаточно статей

Comment: я бы начал с написания интерфейсов, при этом как вы понимаете в паттерне MVP model и view ничего друг о друге не знают и общение между ними происходит исключительно в Presenter'е. Правильное выделение интерфейсов - вот это бы я назвал самым основным моментом. Вот здесь есть хорошая статья с примером http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

Comment: За статью спасибо. Много статей читал и коды на git смотрел. Но я так и не могу понять как в вышеприведенном коде выделить работу с логикой и работу с представлением.. Если делать на каждое маленькое действие отдельную функцию, лишь для того чтобы использовать ее в Presenter/View то количество кода в разы увеличивается, и становиться еще хуже.